# Broken nested tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a problem when I use nested tabs. Everything looks fine if I define the `label` property on `md-tab`, but when I put a `<template md-tab-label>Nested Tab 1</template>` it makes the parent `md-tab-group`'s first tab "Nested Tab 1" instead of "Parent Tab 1".

How do I get around this awkward behavior? Or is this the way it is?

`HTML`:

```html
 <md-tab-group #parentTabs>
    <md-tab label="Parent Tab 1">
        First Tab
        <md-tab-group #childTabs>
            <md-tab>
                <ng-template md-tab-label><span (click)="tabClicked()">Nested Tab 1</span> <a (click)="close()">X</a></ng-template>
                Tab Content
            </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Nested Tab 2">Nested Tab 2 Content</md-tab>
            <md-tab label="Nested Tab 3">Nested Tab 3 Content</md-tab>
        </md-tab-group>
    </md-tab>

    <md-tab label="Parent Tab 2">
        Second Tab
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Parent Tab 3">
        Third Tab
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

[Plunkr demonstrating the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzY0CcPw1iMWj39BdpoQ?p=preview)

Notice how Nested Tab 1 appears on the first parent tab...

Comment: What's the reason to use **template**? Also, `<template>` is deprecated. Use `ng-template` instead.

Comment: No reason, I've updated the code and it looks like the result is the same. The reason for using ng-template is so that I can have click events and stuff within the tab label.

Comment: [**Check this**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BL2N1EVW3WhE1n5d1RHV?p=info).

Comment: @developer033 The thing is I want to be able to add click events/customize the content within tab. I've updated OP with what I am seeing.

Comment: @developer033 upvoted thanks for the plunkr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the root cause, it could be `ContentChild` trying to pick first found descendant instead of child.

That hypothesis led me to a workaround: Put the `<ng-template md-tab-label>` into the parent tab itself, which solved the problem.

```html
<md-tab>
  <ng-template md-tab-label>Parent Tab 1</ng-template>
  First Tab

  <md-tab-group #childTabs>
    <md-tab>
      <ng-template md-tab-label><span (click)="tabClicked()">Nested Tab 1</span> <a (click)="close()">X</a></ng-template>
      Tab Content

    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Nested Tab 2">Nested Tab 2 Content</md-tab>
    <md-tab label="Nested Tab 3">Nested Tab 3 Content</md-tab>
  </md-tab-group>
</md-tab>
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/w0egLBU0aUQpPWbaeQtS?p=preview

Comment: By jove it makes no sense and it shouldn't be like this, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and found that according to the material documentation (https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage) tabs shouldn't be nested.